# Any way to pause firestore listener without removing it?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to pause firestore listener without removing it?

I have multiple firebase listeners, some are dependent on other, that changes or start other listeners on data change. Lets say my first listener starts a second listener its `onSnapshot`. First listener started on `useEffect`. For certain condition I may not want to change the second listener, so I need to discard data change update from first listener.

If condition met (button click), I discard data changes on first listener for a few moments. Currently I'm doing this using a boolean with `useRef`. My react app is working fine, with dependant listeners like this. **I could remove the listener but I do not want to remove and recreate the listener.**

I was wondering if there is a pausing mechanism or method available for any listener. I think it will save a tiny read cost if there was such a method because I'm not using that data sent onSnapshot.

Code example:

```
useEffect(() => {
let  firstListener, secondListener;
//console.log("useEffect...");

function ListenerFunc(p) {
 secondListener = await firestore
    .collection("test") 
    .doc(p)
    .onSnapshot((doc) => {
      //console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());

      //Need to discard unwanted change here. 
      //Changing it on button click for a 2 seconds then it changes back to : pauser.current = false.
      if (pauser.current) {
        console.log("paused for a moment.");
        //pauser.current = false;
        return;
      }
    else {
          //update.
         }
    })
  }

 firstListener = firestore
        .collection("test")
        .doc("tab")
        .onSnapshot((doc) => {
          //console.log("Current data: ", doc.data()); 
          var p = doc.data().p; //get variable p

          ListenerFunc(p);
        });
  // cleanup.
}
```

Comment: You could maintain a variable in your component state that gets updated on the button click and auto-reset with a `setTimeout`. The listener could use or throw away the data based on the state. But I don't think there is a "pause" for event listeners

Comment: @Ayushya what you have described is already mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not possible. If you need to stop listening for changes, even temporarily, you have to detach your listener and attach a new one when you want to start listening again, there is no pause mechanism for listeners.

You could open a Feature Request in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=530136&template=0) if you'd like so that the product team can consider this, but given that this has already been proposed in this [GitHub Feature Request for the IOS SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5390) and it was rejected I don't see this changing anytime soon.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer and clarifying this is not possible yet. I hope we will get such a feature on firebase SDK.